# AWS Timestream: Problems with function : ANY. Either the function does not exist, or there is a problem with a dependent function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-timestream

I'm trying queries with ANY(), SOME() and  ALL(), as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/comparison-functions.all-any-some.html

along the lines of

`SELECT * FROM "mytable"."temperature" WHERE device_name <> ANY('Foo', 'Bar')`

and I'm always getting this error:

Problems with function : ANY. Either the function does not exist, or there is a problem with a dependent function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=964438&#964438

> The keyword VALUES should be used if the comparison values is a list
> of literals e.g. SELECT * FROM "mytable"."temperature" WHERE
> device_name ANY(VALUES 'Foo', 'Bar'). Same for ALL and SOME too. The
> alternative syntax is SELECT * FROM "mytable"."temperature" WHERE
> device_name ANY (SELECT 'Foo' UNION ALL SELECT 'Bar')